# jQuery if div contains this text, replace that part of the text

Tags: jquery, text, replace, contains

Like the title says, I want to replace a specific part of the text in a div.

The structure looks like this:

```
<div class="text_div">
    This div contains some text.
</div>
```

And I want to replace only "contains" with "hello everyone", for example.
I can't find a solution for this.

Comment: What about if the text was 'This div contains some text which contains some letters' and I wish to change the 1st contains, not the 2nd one. Or just select any word and it will be changed by predefined one.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You can use the [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method and pass a function that returns the modified text, using the native [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to perform the replacement:

```
​$(".text_div").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("contains", "hello everyone"); 
});​​​​​
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/wQns7/).

Comment: You can use regex /iwantreplacethis/g for all ocurences

Comment: Thank you so much for this :) one simple question: why doesn't this work without the return

Comment: @AaronMatthews This answer was a very long time ago but I believe it would be because the jQuery `text` method, when passed a function, sets the text of the selection to the return value of that function. Without the `return` the text would be replaced with nothing.

Comment: This solve a complex issue for me, thank you

Answer (score 12):

If it's possible, you could wrap the word(s) you want to replace in a span tag, like so:

```
<div class="text_div">
    This div <span>contains</span> some text.
</div>
```

You can then easily change its contents with jQuery:

```
$('.text_div > span').text('hello everyone');
```

If you can't wrap it in a span tag, you could use regular expressions.

Answer (score 10):

Very simple just use this code, it will preserve the HTML, while removing unwrapped text only:

```
jQuery(function($){

    // Replace 'td' with your html tag
    $("td").html(function() { 

    // Replace 'ok' with string you want to change, you can delete 'hello everyone' to remove the text
          return $(this).html().replace("ok", "hello everyone");  

    });
});
```

Here is full example: https://blog.hfarazm.com/remove-unwrapped-text-jquery/

Answer (score 8):

```
var d = $('.text_div');
d.text(d.text().trim().replace(/contains/i, "hello everyone"));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to search for elements containing a specific text

```
var elem = $('div.text_div:contains("This div contains some text")')​;
elem.text(elem.text().replace("contains", "Hello everyone"));
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: this will replace more than one word if my string contains more than one target words, what will be then?