# Target only one element on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr

It's been a while when I have written JS or jQuery, and I have this newbie problem now. I'm trying to target one element where text is, rather than all elements on page that have same class.

I'm trying to place user's first bold line in photo caption into other element. This code works, but I need to make sure that it's not same. Like if user has 2 photos and other has caption, it should get duplicated as it will in this code.

Heres: my HTML (with Tumblr helpers):

```
{block:Photoset}
                    <div class="photoset-grid" data-layout="{PhotosetLayout}">
                        <div class="photoset-posts">
                            <div class="wrap">
                                {block:Photos}<img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"/>     {/block:Photos}
                            </div>
                            <div class="background-wrap"></div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="post-date" href="{Permalink}">{TimeAgo}</a>
                        {block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
                        <div class="post-details">
                            {block:HasTags}
                            <div class="post-details-tags">
                                {block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}">#{Tag}</a>{/block:Tags}
                            </div>
                            {/block:HasTags}
                            <div class="post-details-buttons">
                                <i>{LikeButton}</i>
                                <i>{ReblogButton}</i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {/block:Photoset}
```

Heres my JS:

```
// variables
var $photoCaption = $(".photo .wrap .caption strong:first-child").text();
var $removableElement = $(".photo .wrap .caption strong:first-child");

// remove original element
$(".photo .caption strong:first-child").parent().remove();
$removableElement.remove();

// place new element to its place
$(".photo .photo-photo").append("<p class='photo-caption'>" + $photoCaption + "</p>");
```

Thanks, all.

Comment: What is your question?  And, where's the HTML?  We can only help you target one particular HTML element in the page if we can see the HTML that you're trying to target (including all relevant parent tags).  FYI, you may want to use jQuery's `.replaceWith()` which does both remove and add in one step.

Comment: @jfriend00 Okay, wait a second.

Comment: Not sure if i understood the question properly. is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324559/jquery-if-div-contains-this-text-replace-that-part-of-the-text

Comment: Please upload some html for reference

Comment: @KD Here's the scenario: User submit makes first line on Tumblr caption to bold and I'm trying to get that first bold into another element, which I will place on top of another picture. It's like an image caption.

Comment: I think we need to see the actual HTML that the browser sees because that's what jQuery is operating on, not the template.  Then, in your HTML please identify exactly what you're trying to get from that HTML.

Comment: @jfriend00 It takes '.photo .wrap .caption strong:first-child' and put's it into another div. But I need to make sure that it won't duplicate that caption to another same named div. Do you need more info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jsFiddle you posted in response to jfriend was helpful in clarifying what you meant.

I think I'd try something like the following:

```
$(".photo .caption").each(function() {
    var $strongChildren = $(this).children('strong');
    if ($strongChildren.length > 0) { 
        var $removableElement = $(".photo .caption").children('strong').first();
        var $photoCaption = $removableElement.text();

        // remove original element
        $removableElement.remove();

        // place new element to its place
        $(this).siblings(".photo-photo").append("<p class='photo-caption'>" + $photoCaption + "</p>");
    }
});
```

There are other ways you could do it.  For instance, you could also find all of the first-child strings and then call `$removableElement.closest('.photo');` to get only its containing `.photo` element.

The above code should work, though. Let me know if you have any problems.