# Replace text of select form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with the following `select`

```
<div class="styled-select styled-input">
   <select name="upcp-sort-by" id="upcp-sort-by" onchange="UPCP_Sort_By();">
       <option value="price_asc">Price (Ascending)</option>
       <option value="price_desc">Price (Descending)</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

and I want to replace with jquery/JavaScript the text of the select with another text. I tried this from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324559/jquery-if-div-contains-this-text-replace-that-part-of-the-text) :

```
 $(".styled-select").text(function () {
     return $(this).text().replace("Price (Ascending)", "Vol (Ascending)"); 
 });
```

but it ruins the select option..

```js
$(".styled-select").text(function() {
  return $(this).text().replace("Price (Ascending)", "Vol (Ascending)");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="styled-select styled-input">
  <select name="upcp-sort-by" id="upcp-sort-by" onchange="UPCP_Sort_By();">
       <option value="price_asc">Price (Ascending)</option>
       <option value="price_desc">Price (Descending)</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

How can I replace correctly only the text of the select?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery if div contains this text, replace that part of the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324559/jquery-if-div-contains-this-text-replace-that-part-of-the-text)

Comment: if you see my question, I am using that answer of the question that you suggest and it didn't work for me!

Comment: The difference is that the element for which you are trying to change the text is `$(".styled-select")` which is the `<div>` that surrounds the `<select>`. You need to change not the div, not even the select, but an option inside the select.

Comment: @PeterB Thanks for the info ! You noted what was wrong with the solution I posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes

- You need to change the text of `option`, instead of the `select` element.
- You need to set the replaced value back to `option` element.

i.e.

```
$(".styled-select option").each(function() {
  $(this).text( $(this).text().replace("Price (Ascending)", "Vol (Ascending)") );
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(".styled-select option").each(function() {
  $(this).text( $(this).text().replace("Price (Ascending)", "Vol (Ascending)") );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="styled-select styled-input">
  <select name="upcp-sort-by" id="upcp-sort-by" onchange="UPCP_Sort_By();">
       <option value=""></option><option value="price_asc">Price (Ascending)</option>
       <option value="price_desc">Price (Descending)</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Or use `contains` to narrow down the `option`s to iterate

```
$(".styled-select option:contains(Price (Ascending))").each(function() {
  $(this).text( $(this).text().replace("Price (Ascending)", "Vol (Ascending)") );
});
```

Comment: Good answer, I think however that it can do without the `return`?

Comment: @Ele You mean iterate only those options which has the text to be replaced?

Comment: @PeterB You are right, `return` wasn't adding anything.

Comment: Now is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a clean code that will first select the `option` element with that text you want to replace and then replace the `text` content of that `option`:

```js
//get the desired option
var option = $(".styled-select option:contains(Price (Ascending))");
//replace the text
var replacedText = option.text().replace("Price (Ascending)", "Vol (Ascending)");
//set the replaced text
option.text(replacedText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="styled-select styled-input">
   <select name="upcp-sort-by" id="upcp-sort-by" onchange="UPCP_Sort_By();">
       <option value="price_asc">Price (Ascending)</option>
       <option value="price_desc">Price (Descending)</option>
   </select>
</div>
```