# CSS/HTML to change the font colour of just 'full stop punctuations'

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've scoured this site but can't seem to find a solution that works.

I'd like to apply a rule, site-wide that change the font colour of all full stop punctuations.

The site is a basic wordpress site.

I'd rather not to it via a  as I'd like to leave the site owner to update the site himself and this to update automatically, without the worry of him 'coding'.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The reason you can't find this, is because it doesn't exist. CSS isn't content aware - meaning, it doesn't care what the text actually is. What you could do, is use `the_content` filter and then wrap all full stop punctuation in an element, that you could then target. [Codex for the_content filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/)

Comment: You could do it with jquery or php just replace all . with <k>.</k> for example then target it in css k{color:red} https://stackoverflow.com/a/11324598/10634638

Comment: You can do this using JavaScript but don't do it that way. The best way to do it is to use classes. e.g. `<div class="punc">.</div>` and then color them using that class or id.