# Replace all text using the given object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to replace the text in the HTML which could be similar to the following

```
<span>Hello, I like mangoes.</span> 
Mango is also the <b>king</b> of fruits.
<p>Which fruit <div> is called the queen of fruits </div> </p>
```

using the given map:

```
{
   "Hello, I like mangoes." : "New String",
   "Mango is also the " : "New String 1",
   "king" : "New String 2",
   "of fruits": "New String 3"
   .
   ..
}
```

How could I use `jquery` to replace all source strings with the values in the map?

The transformed HTML will hence look like:

```
<span>New String</span>
New String 1 <b>New String 2</b> New String 3
. . .
```

Comment: this post answer in stackoverflow
[jQuery if div contains this text, replace that part of the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324559/jquery-if-div-contains-this-text-replace-that-part-of-the-text)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function replace($el, old, new_val){
  $el.html(function() { 
    return $(this).html().split(old).join(new_val);
  });
}

const $el = $('.container');

const data = {
   "Hello, I like mangoes." : "New String",
   "Mango is also the " : "New String 1",
   "king" : "New String 2",
   "of fruits": "New String 3",
};

for (let [old, new_val] of Object.entries(data)){
  replace($el, old, new_val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <span>Hello, I like mangoes.</span> 
  Mango is also the <b>king</b> of fruits.
  <p>Which fruit <div> is called the queen of fruits </div> </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've got your source strings as keys in an object, you'll want to use `Object.keys()`. For best results, you're going to want your text to all be within a single parent object.

```js
const map = {
  "Hello, I like mangoes.": "New String",
  "Mango is also the ": "New String 1",
  "king": "New String 2",
  "of fruits": "New String 3"
}

const run = () => {
  $("#box").html(function() {
    let text = $(this).html();
    Object.entries(map).forEach(([k, v]) => text = text.replace(new RegExp(k, 'g'), v));
    return text;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="box">
  <span>Hello, I like mangoes.</span> Mango is also the <b>king</b> of fruits.
  <p>Which fruit is called the queen of fruits?</p>
</div>

<button onclick="run()">Run</button>
```

Using a `new RegExp` lets you use the `g` flag for global replacement.