# Change the text of a drop down menu item to something else using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I am using Thinkific, a learning CMS, that allows me to inject custom JS to my site using a section they have called "Site footer code". The platform allows for automatic translation, but we want to change one of the words to a better translation (Apoyo to Soporte). They haven't enabled the Custom CSS wide feature to me, but I am allowed to use custom JS in the the Site footer code section. It tells me I need to wrap te code in a  tag.

Is there a solution?

Here is an image of what the code looks like when seeing it in Chrome:
[image: Code in Chrome]

I tried following a tutorial from W3Schools around JS replacement, but couldn't get it to work. I am not sure what to do because as far as I know I can edit "the original code", just add Javascript to change what I am seeing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery if div contains this text, replace that part of the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324559/jquery-if-div-contains-this-text-replace-that-part-of-the-text)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
const item = document.querySelector('.dropdown___menu-item > a');

if (item.text === "Apoyo") {
    item.text = "Soporte";
}
```